# identify global symbols in lambda expressions

Tags: python, lambda

I need to get the list of names of all symbols which I must have available in order to evaluate or execute a piece of code. I tried to use `symtable` module but it seems that it does not handle properly lambdas and inner functions (`def`s inside other code). Consider this:

```
import symtable
symtable.symtable("x+y", '<string>', 'exec').get_symbols()
```

I get this: `[<symbol 'y'>, <symbol 'x'>]` which is exactly what I expect.

but when I write this:

```
symtable.symtable("z=lambda x: x+y; z(10)", '<string>', 'exec').get_symbols()
```

the results is: `[<symbol 'z'>]` and I have no info about `x` (never mind, it is a local variable) nor `y` (which is global and this is what I need).

But when I try to evaluate this with `exec("z=lambda x: x+y; z(10)")` the value of `y` is missing. Is there a way I can identify the names of all symbols which must be supplied to an expression or code so that it can be evaluated/executed?

Comment: Oh, I get it! Shame on me... I can look into the child symbol table of `z`! It is always like that, I discover the solution myself just a minute after posting the question on SO. :)

Comment: Consider posting that as an answer (ideally with a brief example).  It may be helpful to others who have this same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Without much ado... I need to look into child symbol tables. Recursion is the tool of choice:

```
import symtable

def find_global_symbols(table):
    symbols = set()
    for t in table.get_children():
        symbols |= find_global_symbols(t)
    symbols |= set(s.get_name() for s in table.get_symbols() if s.is_global())
    return symbols

table = symtable.symtable("z=lambda x: x+y; z(10)", '<string>', 'exec')
global_symbols = find_global_symbols(table)
```

Which gives me `y` as the answer. This is what I need. Now I know that I have to supply the value of `y` to be able to execute the code in question.

UPDATE: actually there is a possible improvement if I take into account the names which are imported in each scope

```
def find_global_symbols(table, imports):
    imports = imports | set(s.get_name() for s in table.get_symbols() if s.is_imported())
    symbols = set()
    for s in table.get_symbols():
        if s.is_global() and s.get_name() not in imports:
            symbols.add(s.get_name())
    for t in table.get_children():
        symbols |= find_global_symbols(t, imports)
    return symbols

table = symtable.symtable("z=lambda x: x+y; z(10)", '<string>', 'exec')
global_symbols = find_global_symbols(table, set())
```